# Does bash support a regex replace + default value at the same time?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a problem where I want to strip front slashes out of a `bash` environment variable *and* simultaneously give a default value if the variable isn't set at all. I need to be able to do this within an expression that is assignable to a variable.

In `zsh`, the simple solution is:

```
newvar=${${oldvar:-default}//\//}
```

But I'm constrained by the project I'm working on to use `bash`. Is there an expression I can use to replicate the right-hand side of the above assignment in `bash`?

---

Some example test cases (*oldvar* → *newvar*)

- *<not set>* → `"default"`
- `"/"` → `""`
- `"hello world"` → `"hello world"`
- `"hello/world//!`" → `"helloworld!"`

Comment: Think you'll have to do them separately

Comment: Or use an external tool like awk, sed

Comment: Note that parameter expansions uses patterns, not regular expressions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this :

```
: ${oldvar:=default} ; newvar="${oldvar##*/}"
```

This is still two separate statements, but quite concise.  Here is what they do :

1. `: ${oldvar:=default}` uses the `:` "noop" and feeds as an argument an expansion that will cause `oldvar` to be assigned a default value if it is null or unset (this is what `:=` does).  This is not just an expansion, there is a (permanent) assignment involved.
2. `newvar="${oldvar##*/}"` strips all leading slashes from the value of `oldvar`, and then assigns the resulting value to `newvar`.  It does that because `##` matching the longest that starts at the beginning of the value of `oldvar` and matches with the following pattern `*/`, which means any sequence of zero or more characters that end with a slash.

Comment: There's one requirement I didn't phrase very well (or at all) in my question, which is that I need to phrase this as an expression so that it is, in turn, assignable to a variable. The reason is that the expression (what I've put on the RHS of "newvar=") is actually a sub-component of a larger expression.

Comment: OK, this modification to your solution seems to do it:
    `newvar=$(: ${oldvar:=default} ; tmp="${oldvar//\//}" ; echo $tmp)`
The difference being that now I can use the RHS of the assignment as part of a bigger expression...

Comment: Accepted this answer as the first one to capture the "spirit" of what I need :)

Comment: @0xbe5077ed Strictly speaking, you need to use `echo "$tmp"`; the quotes are important depending on what `oldvalue` contained.

Answer (score 1):

bash doesn't allow nested substitutions. i agree with Fred's solution (i can't comment it) but i think that

```
: ${oldvar:=default} ; newvar="${oldvar//\//}"
```

best suits the test cases.

Comment: OP says he wants to strip leading slashes only, but `${oldvar//\//}` strips them all (including non-leading slashes).

Comment: Not leading slashes. Forward slashes ("front slashes").

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function.

```
function sanitize () {
   local v="${1:-default}"
   echo "${v//\//}"
}

newvar="$(sanitize "$oldvar")"
```

Alternatively,

```
function sanitize () {
   local v="${!$1}"
   : ${v:=default}
   echo "${v//\//}"
}

newvar="$(sanitize oldvar)"
```

You can replace `"${v//\//}"` with `"${v##*/}"` or similar expansion, depending on what you really want.